# 64bit method call slow C#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, optimization, 64-bit

HI i have a 32bit application being ported to 64bit 
somehow method calls of 64bit is a lot slower than 32bit.

code example

```
    class huge_class
{
 class subclass0{}
 class subclass1{}
 class subclass2{}
 class subclass3{}
 class subclass4{}
 class subclass5{}
 class subclass6{}
 class subclass7{}
 //so on... say 300

 private object[] GetClassObj(Stopwatch x)
 {
       Console.WriteLine(x.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); //<- the latency can be observed here, the time it takes to execute this line takes a big amount of time
       object[] retObj = new object[300];
       retObj[0] = new subclass0();
       retObj[1] = new subclass1();
       retObj[2] = new subclass2();
       retObj[3] = new subclass3();
       retObj[4] = new subclass4();
       retObj[5] = new subclass5();
       retObj[6] = new subclass6();
            //so on... to 299
 }
}

    Class CallingClass{
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Ready");
        Console.ReadKey();
        huge_class bigClass = new huge_class();
        Console.WriteLine("Init Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Stopwatch tmr = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        object[] WholeLottaObj = bigClass.GetClassObj(tmr);
        Console.WriteLine(tmr.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

for some odd reason on 32bit the GetClassObj is entered faster than on its 64bit version 
what am i doing wrong

Comment: show the code which calls GetClassObj

Comment: Why on earth do you have 300 subclasses. Could you give a more practical example, and how much slower is it actually?

Comment: @michael, not very clear: did you compile your code under 64bit and run or just run your binary compilef for 32 bit?

Comment: The design doesn't smell right at all, but at least to soothe your pain a bit: `object[] retObj = Enumerable.Range(0, 300).Select(n => Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", "MyClass.subclass" + n)).ToArray();`. -- this can even be parallellized automatically using PLinq, if classes don't use overlapping references.

Comment: What real world problem are you trying to solve? Even if instantiating 300 classes takes 3 times as long on 64 bit, this is not a big deal if you only do it once.

Comment: the program example is used for CodeCompiler usage using codedom. classes are being built from .ini files and then compiled and retrieved by GetClassObj. in one of the inifiles it is around 27000+ arrays being build running at 86bit - 5sec while in the 32bit version running more or less a minute

Comment: please note guys that the slowdown occurs in "Entering the function" not in the total execution time of the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be due to cache coherency. Don't forget that each reference will be twice as large on a 64-bit machine as it is on a 32-bit machine. That means:

- Each of your instance objects is going to be bigger, so they'll be spread out further in memory (there's more per-object overhead in x64 anyway, and any reference fields will be twice the size)
- The array itself will be about twice as big

Now it could easily be that in the 32-bit CLR you were just within one of the fastest caches on your CPU - whereas on the 64-bit CLR you've gone outside it so it's having to swap memory in and out of that cache, either to another cache or to main memory.

That's why x86 is the default for executable projects in VS2010 (and possibly 2008; not sure). [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/8/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx) goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. so what could i do to make it load a little faster. thou it seems weird because the performance hit is so high compared to 32bit

Comment: @michael: Just how high? You haven't shown any figures. Do you know if the problem is due to the constructor calls or storing the values in an array? A bit of investigation would really help here...

Comment: x86bit version entry is made in 5096ms while the 64bit version enters the function at around 76000+ i am passing the stopwatch to the function to determine the exact time the function has been called. figures come from a 40000 size array

Comment: @michael: Is that just creating the array *once*? Is it any faster the second time? (Maybe you're paying more for type initialization.) How many actual different classes have you got? What do you mean by "enters the function at around 76000"? It sounds like you're logging how long some operations *before* the code you've posted has executed... what are you actually timing?

Comment: i am only testing this code to pass only once. no second pass. the initilization class of the huge class is fast but what bothers me is the time it takes to actually "Find" and "Enter" GetClassObj. in the real code there is a lot of different classes but from my testing the problem really occurs on the time it takes to actually Find and Enter GetClassObj

Comment: @michael: Right - so the code you've shown us is completely irrelevant - it's the code which executes *before* you get to `GetClassObj` which is important. Unfortunately we have no idea what that's doing...

Comment: i have updated the code on top for the main. to give you guys a clearer view of the problem.

Comment: @michael: Thanks, that makes it a lot clearer... but more puzzling too. So you're genuinely *only* timing how long it takes to enter the `GetClassObj` method? How big is the method? (This could just be JIT compilation if it's enormous.)

Comment: yes i am only timing how long it takes to enter the class. that is the whole code i am trying to resolve. i have isolated the problem to that point only as of now. i think it is something related to JIT what is really puzzling is how slow it is performing in the 64bit version. am i missing a attribute or something? any suggestion is most welcomed :D

Comment: @michael: I suspect the 64-bit JIT compiler tries harder to optimize the code, as it's more likely to be used in server farms for long running tasks. You should be able to see this in perfmon, I believe - I think there's a performance counter for JIT compilation time. That really is a frighteningly long time though - is it on a VM, or in a debugger, or anything like that? How long is the method?

Comment: i have ANTS profiler and it saying that the time it takes is on JIT Overhead is there an option to lessen or stop JIT Optimization, i am running this on a native 32bit and 64bit Machine no Virtual Machine. as for the method thats the whole method i just need to return the whole array of class objects.

Comment: @michael: It may well be type initialization then - if that's the first reference to all of those types.

Comment: here is a link to the ANTS Performance Profiler Result http://www.mediafire.com/?md939yw4lwf110m

Comment: @michael: Thanks - that's showing 10 seconds rather than 76 though - why the difference? Note that the *second* call to GetClassObj should be a lot faster - that may be worth checking.

Comment: Hi Jon i have checked the second and succesive calls to GetClassObj and yes it is a lot faster. is there any method/technique to make sure that on the first call it is up and ready so that the performance hit is not visible?

Comment: @michael: It depends on what your application is doing. If you don't need the class right away, you could call GetClassObj once in a background thread when your application starts. In fact, I *think* there's some way you can request that a method is JIT compiled without actually running it, but I'm not sure...

Comment: i think the method you are talking about is NGEN.exe i am currently trying this now. hopefully it works

Comment: @michael: No, I'm not talking about ngen. I'm talking about a method you can run on an individual method or class...

Comment: ngen works but i cannot use this. because huge_class is made and compiled during runtime. hmm i am not sure i understand your suggestion Jon :|

Comment: @michael: I'm saying that I think that somewhere in the framework there's a method you can call at execution time to say "make sure this method is JIT compiled please". I just can't find it right now...

Comment: ive found something that actually helped speed things up. Type.GetNestedTypes() seems to return everything very fast.

Comment: @michael: That can return the `Type` references quickly, but that doesn't mean everything's been JIT compiled yet...

Answer (score 1):

Why it should be faster in the first place? 64-bit pointer operations are twice as heavy (in memory terms), so it's natural for 64-bit app to be slower.